# How to schedule jobs and passing arguments in linux and running in parallel

Tags: linux, bash, scheduled-tasks, jobs

I want to run an script at a specific time at background. The job receive an input argument. In order to schedule a job, I found out that I should use the at command and run it like this:

```
at -f ./myjob now
```

and it works. However when I want to run it with an argument like this :

```
at -f ./myjob 1 now
```

it gives me the Garbled time error message. Does anyone have any idea how to solve the problem?

Update :
I want to run the job with different parameters in parallel. like this

```
at -f ./myjob 1 now

at -f ./myjob 2 now

at -f ./myjob 3 now
```

Comment: `echo "./myjob 1" | at now` is perhaps what you are looking for... Or, alternatively, `at now <<< "./myjob 1"`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `at` command has the `-f file` option which reads commands from a file rather than standard input. Therefore put your commands in a file, for example `cmds`, which would contain the following:

```
./myjob 1
```

To run multiple jobs in parallel use the ampersand operator to fork each job:

```
./myjob 1 &
./myjob 2 &
./myjob 3
```

Then run:

```
at -f ./cmds now
```

More information can be found by reading the `at` man page, via `man at`.

Comment: I want to run it this job in parallel with different input value. If I put it in one file,  then it will be executed in series not in parallel

Comment: sorry, I made the changes in my question.

Comment: @user2373198 glad I could help. I would also take twalberg's approach of piping the commands or using here strings into consideration as well. It all just depends on the situation.